# How to fix wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"}) on Ubuntu?

Tags: nodejs, npm

When i tried to install `npm install -g react-native-cli`
 then i faced an error like below :

```
npm WARN engine react-native-cli@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/putuguna/.npm/react-native-cli/1.0.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-16-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /home/putuguna
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/putuguna/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Could you help me for solve my problem

**Update :**

One thing that i know, i should update my node js version. I have done, by this way :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But the error above appears again. please help

Comment: Consider installing Node 6.x instead of Node 4.x.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/786272/why-does-installing-node-6-x-on-ubuntu-16-04-actually-install-node-4-2-6/786279#786279

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't already, you might want to have a look at the [instructions by nodesource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/OLDER_DISTROS.md#user-content-debian-style-distributions).

It looks like you're running Ubuntu 14.04.  An upgrade to 16.04 would solve the problem, if this is an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues because while the older version was run by the command `node`, the new version was renamed to `nodejs`.

So `node` never unreturned an error but launched the older version. `nodejs` worked fine.  I had to do a bit of soft linking to fix this.

I've forgotten the exact procedure but you can run following to see if both exist but point to different programs

```
which node
which nodejs
```